# Postgres data compress

Tags: postgresql, compression, columnstore

I am using Postgres ( 12.5 ver on ubuntu OS and it is community edition).
I am looking for columnstore features in postgres. While creating column store index it is giving me `ERROR: access method "columnstore" does not exist`.

Also i am looking for other option like `default_table_access_method = zedstore;` It is showing the error as listed below
`ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "default_table_access_method": "zedstore" DETAIL:  Table access method "zedstore" does not exist.`

Please can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: The community edition of Postgres does not have column store.

Comment: Please be more diligent next time, and properly format your code ;-)

Comment: Looks like Greenplum